# PHP DOM Parser only working for some pages

Tags: php, parsing, dom, curl

I'm using: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ and noticed that in the examples, and trying to scrape certain sites, only some of them return results.

I'm using:

```
include_once('../../simple_html_dom.php');

// Create DOM from URL or file
$website = 'http://www.digg.com/';
$html = file_get_html($website);

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
   echo "<img src=\"" . $website . $element->src . "\"" . '<br>';
```

Which shows a bunch of thumbnails, but they are pretty much blank (and it's not returning all thumbnails).

Is it because they have some sort of htaccess restrictions on people? This happens for multiple websites.

Comment: You are not telling what exactly goes wrong. Can you show an example?

Comment: I think you're probably assuming that the external site always has valid HTML.  You might want to run the sites that don't work thru an HTML Validator

Comment: Try and just echo the images' source. If it's empty, you'll know something's gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assuming that $element->src is always relative to $website which it could easily not be...

For example: $element->src could already be http://www.digg.com/image.jpg so then doing $website . $element->src would be http://www.digg.com/http://www.digg.com/image.jpg and that wouldn't work...

Try

```
include_once('../../simple_html_dom.php');

// Create DOM from URL or file
$website = 'http://www.digg.com/';
$html = file_get_html($website);

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
   //dont want double slashes
   $src = ltrim($element->src, '/');
   //dont want double urls
   $src = str_replace($website, "", $src);

   echo "<img src=\"" . $website . $src . "\"" . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. It worked by removing $website from echo `"<img src=\"" . $website . $src . "\"" . '<br>';` ultimately giving me `echo "<img src=\"" . $src . "\"" . '<br>'`. Thanks!